How to only store the changing data within certain level before writing data into Apache IoTDB?
My scenario need to achieve real-time alarm, so I want Apache IoTDB database to store time series data only when the data changes. The data that has not changed or has not changed within the changing data level set should not be stored in IoTDB. I wonder if IoTDB can be set to achieve this need, and how should I set it. Also, if I change the settings for this, do I need to restart IoTDB server?

You can use trigger function in Apache IoTDB to achieve what you need. Trigger of IoTDB can be set to BEFORE INSERT, which means to trigger before the data is persisted, so you can write a command to check if the data is changed, and then generate this trigger to only keep the changed data. For your other question, IoTDB allows users to dynamically register and uninstall triggers without starting or stopping the server, so you don't need to restart IoTDB.
